# Run Surefire tests in Maven with HTML output & a nonzero exit code on failure

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm working on a Gitlab CI/CD pipeline for various Dockerized Java apps, using Maven to build them. The first step of the pipeline builds the app and pushes it to our registry. The second step is supposed to run unit tests and ensure they all pass before allowing the pipeline to continue to the deployment stage.

The problem I'm having is finding a way to invoke Maven which does what I want. What I need the test step to do is:

1. Execute the tests once with Surefire
2. Print to STDOUT or STDERR the test results (so they are visible in the job log)
3. Output XML test reports which will be uploaded to Gitlab as job artifacts (which will be parsed by Gitlab to populate the test results in the web GUI)
4. Output an HTML test report which will be uploaded to Gitlab as a job artifact (to give a downloadable, human-readable, all-in-one summary of the test results)
5. Exit with a nonzero return code if and only if any tests failed (so that the pipeline job will be marked as failed in the Gitlab pipeline)

1-3 are handled automatically by Surefire. The problem is 4 & 5; I'm using the Surefire-report plugin to generate the HTML report, but I can't find a way to invoke it which does what I want:

- If I invoke `mvn 'test' 'surefire-report:report'`, then, if any tests fail, Maven exits with a nonzero exit code but the HTML report is not generated.

  - I think this is because, in the case of a failed test, Maven considers the `test` goal to have failed and exits without running the `surefire-report` goal at all
  - If there are no failed tests, then the `surefire-report` goal does run and the report is generated, but a report that's only generated when everything passed is of limited use.
- If I invoke `mvn 'surefire-report:report'` or `mvn 'surefire-report:report' 'test'`, then, if any tests fail, an HTML report is still generated, but the return code is 0.

  - I think this is because Maven considers the `surefire-report` goal to be successful as long as it successfully generates a report, and then considers the `test` goal to be redundant because it already ran the tests in order to generate the report
- My current workaround is `mvn 'surefire-report:report' && mvn 'test'`, which works, but also runs the tests twice (or at least prints their results to STDOUT twice), and also requires the Docker container in which the tests are run to use a shell script instead of running a single Maven command
- Someone suggested `mvn 'test' ; result=$? ; mvn 'surefire-report:report-only' && exit ${result}`, which seems to work, but I'd much rather have a single command rather than a shell script

Comment: `The first step of the pipeline builds the app and pushes it to our registry. The second step is supposed to run unit tests and ensure they all pass before allowing the pipeline to continue to the deployment stage.`  So you are building your application before you run your tests? Do I understand that correctly? If so you are doing things wrong.. Maven has a life cycle which compiles the code, compiles the test code and anfterwards runs the unit tests if those are not failing it packages the application (building jar or alike), running integration tests and finally deploying to a registry.

Comment: I strongly recommend to read https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html and follow the life cycle.